# Remove Trailingzeros from StringBuilder object

Tags: java

I   have one stringBuilder object which contains  binary number string.  I  want to remove trailing zeros from this.  because in ans i am reversing this sb object so output will be without leading zeros.

```
//sb = 01111110  --  reversed   output i want after sb reverse - 1111110.

//try1
int k = sb.length() - 1;
while (k >= 0 && sb.charAt(k) == '0') {
    k++;
}

// try2
if (carry != 0) sb.append(carry);

System.out.println(sb);

int ind = 0;
for (int k = sb.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    char p = sb.charAt(i);
    if (p != '0') {
        ind = k;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("TTT" + sb.toString().substring(0, ind));

System.out.println("A" + sb);

return sb.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: try  ```sb.deleteCharAt(0);```

Comment: there can be multiple leading zeros

Comment: It seems you're asking how to remove _trailing_ zeros, despite the question's title. In your "try 1", you start at the end and _add 1 to k_ - why? Where do you think k will go after adding 1 to it when it's already at the end? Think about your algorithm.

Comment: There are formatting issues that make it hard to help you. Please see this [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
while(sb.charAt(0) == '0') {
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
}
```